# How to remove color from bromostyrene/dibromostyrene

Tags: everyday-chemistry, kinetics, solubility, polymers, distillation

Distillation under low heat can remove color (excess bromine) but this is time consuming and there is a danger of bromostyrene polymerization even with added TBC.
In aqueous, sodium thiosulphate can react with bromine to produce sodium bromide, which is water clear, but I don't know if this reaction will take place in pure bromostyrene/dibromostyrene. Additionally, since I am later polymerizing the bromostyrene, any additives that will interfere with polymerization will need to be removed.
Any comments or ideas on how to 'remove' typical yellow-orange-browm color from bromostyrene/dibromostyrene would be much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity I wonder why you selected the "everyday-chemistry" tag?

Comment: If the organic mixture is treated by sodium thiosulfate to remove $\ce{Br2}$, the created ions bromide and sulfate will remain in the aqueous phase. Practically no thiosulfate will remain in the organic mixture that may interfere with future polymerization.

Comment: I second a thiosulfate/metabisulfite wash